# PHP mail() sends emails using "anonymous@..."

Tags: php

I have tried the following with little success:

```
    $fromEmail = "something.com <noreply@something.com>\r\n";

    $headers = 'From: '.$fromEmail;
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$fromEmail;  
    $headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$fromEmail;
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\n';
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { echo "1"; exit; }
```

I have tried commenting out the `Reply-To:` and `Return-Path:` lines as well as replacing the `if(...` line with:

```
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,'-fnoreply@something.com')) { ...
```

In all cases the email arrives but is from `anonymous@...`

Comment: You're missing the CR in your MIME version header (`'\r\n'` instead of `'\n'`).  Also, it seems like including the CRLF in `$fromEmail` is a bad idea -- I'd put it in the code that builds up the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code.

You are missing a dot in MIME header line.

should be:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$fromEmail;
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$fromEmail;  
$headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$fromEmail;
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\n';
<...>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like anonymous@... is your envelope "from" address. The envelope "from" address is different from the address that appears in your "From:" header of the email. It is what sendmail uses in its "MAIL FROM/RCPT TO" exchange with the receiving mail server.The main reason it is called an "envelope" address is that appears outside of the message header and body, in the raw SMTP exchange between mail servers.

To change the envelope "from" address on unix, you specify an "-f" option to your sendmail binary. You can do this globally in php.ini by adding the "-r" option to the "sendmail_path" command line. You can also do it programmatically from within PHP by passing -f mail@something.com as the additional parameter argument to the mail() function (the 5th argument).

**In the php.ini you can add default from address like this**

```
sendmail_from = me@something.com
```

Comment: This would be applied to all the scripts that use the mail function on the domain though :(

Answer (score 1):

To change the *envelope mail from*, you can use the fifth argument. This is used for options that should be passed directly to `sendmail`. Here, you should add `-f info@mywebaddress.com`. A simple example is shown below.

```
mail('recipient@domain.com', 'Subject', 'Message',
  'From: info@myaddress.info','-f info@myaddress.info');
```

And also, all of this is mentioned in [the official PHP manual on `mail()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).